# AWS Lambda function gives error node js when executing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'redis'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'redis'",
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're trying to run? Please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking a good question :)

Comment: The error message suggests that you are importing a module named `redis` that is not available as part of your deployment package. You will need to include it in the zip file. See: [AWS Lambda Deployment Package in Node.js - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html)